how to instruct mysqld to only log to stderr on linux without using a log file path?
I need to run mysql servers on linux (ubuntu 24) and have them log to stderr.
It is possible to pass the argument --log-error to instruct mysqld where to write error logs to, but if I pass --log-error=/dev/stderr, mysql appends .err resulting in --log-error=/dev/stderr.err, and then it tries to log into a file in the data directory instead of to stderr.
if I don't pass --log-error at all, mysql is supposed to log to stderr, which it does, but, it relies on a file path to exist, and aborts if it doesn't:
[Server] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for error logging: Permission denied

I cannot create /var/log/mysql or give it the needed permissions (there will be multiple mysqlds running at once owned by different users, so if I were to do this, I'd need to specify a different log file per one in different paths)
Is there no way to make mysqld log to stderr without depending on /var/log/mysql?

AFAIK, logging writes to a file in all cases. What would be the purpose of logging at all if you're just going to throw away the content in the terminal? The entire point of logging is to give you information to review to track down problems or issues. If you don't want that, why are you logging at all?

@KenWhite I'm not running an actual mysqld server for the purpose of being used as a server, I have a test suite that tests a list of tools written to be used with mysql, and it tests them on different mysql versions. The test code starts various mysqld instances, parses their error logs to determine whether each test passed or not, and then shuts down the mysqld. There is no purpose for keeping the logs, the entire thing is an automated test process.

If log-error is empty it goes to stderr.
On systemd based services this is a good default as it will end up in the journal, accessible via journalctl -u mysql.service

Right, but even if it's empty the server fails during startup because it depends on /var/log/mysql to exist (which might not). That's the problem this thread exists to solve.

its reading the config somewhere that sets it. Look at my_print_defaults --mysqld and see if there's a /var/log/mysql. Consider using --no-defaults as first mysqld argument.

I am using --no-defaults which is why I got surprised the /var/log/mysql issue happens
